# Cannot save passwords on Firefox

Tags: authentication, firefox, passwords, credentials

I am trying to save a login locally in Firefox:

[image]

but the password is never saved: next time I open a Firefox window, I am asked the credentials again.

So I went to Settings > Privacy and Security > Saved Logins > Create New login, in order to save the credentials manually, but I came up with "An error occurred while trying to save this password" :

[image]

I could not find any log file. I am using Firefox 92.0.1 (latest version as of today) on Windows 10.

Does anybody have a clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to re-install Firefox. Actually, when un-installing Firefox, Firefox suggested me to the update its own installation (instead of un-installing it), which I accepted. That solved the problem: as expected, now my credentials are saved.